# Any idea how to disable the NX bit in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, buffer-overflow

I know that Linux provides default implementation of the NX (Non- Executable Bit) to prevent buffer overflow attacks,
You can also check the status of the bit by:

```
dmesg | grep NX
```

But how do you disable it using the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command `sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0` or edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` like this :

`kernel.randomize_va_space = 0`